# Как передать ссылку через массив данных в PHP

Tags: php, opencart

У меня имеется цикл который берет значения из массива и генерирует блоки на основе этих данных.

Как я могу через цикл придать `$service_item['name']` ссылку `$service_item['href']`;

```
$data = array(
    array(
      'name' => 'Охота', 
      'subtitle' => 'Сроки и виды охоты', 
      'description' => '', 
      'image' => 'okhota.jpg', 
      'price' => '<i>3</i> 000', 
      'href' => ' okhota.ru'),
    array(
      'name' => 'Рыбалка', 
      'subtitle' => 'Виды рыбалки', 
      'description' => '', 
      'image' => 'rybalka.jpg', 
      'price' => '<i>2</i> 000',  
      'href' => 'rybalka.ru'),
);
```

Вот цикл с помощью которого я подставляю значения переменных

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 right">
  <div class="price-wrapper">
    <!-- <button class="btn heading">
      <? php print $service_item['btn']; ?>
    </button> -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 left">
    <div class="heading"><?php print $service_item['name']; ?></div>
    <?php if ($service_item['subtitle']) { ?>
    <div class="info"><?php print $service_item['subtitle']; ?> <i></i></div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>   
  <div class="col-12 text">
    <p><?php print $service_item['description']; ?></p>
  </div>    
  <div class="col-12 price-wrap">
    <div class="price heading">
      От <span><?php print $service_item['price']; ?></span> Рублей</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: ссылка $service_item['href'] выводится **точно так же** как $service_item['name']

Comment: Я пытался вывести $service_item['href'] в теге *<a>* вот так _<a href="<?php print $service_item['href']; ?>"_ <a/> но это было бы слишком просто что бы работать, подскажите пожалуйста как мне вывести эту ссылку  как текст $service_item['name']
То-есть как мне сделать текст и ссылку единым целым в цикле

Comment: синтаксис тега <a> **не такой**. Сначала потренируйся со статической ссылкой. Посмотри в учебнике как пишутся ссылки в ХТМЛ. добавь в свой код любую ссылку без РНР. Когда заработает - замени ссылку на значение переменной из РНР.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы используете перебор массивов, то лучше немного изменить структуру:

```php
<?php
$data = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Охота',
        'subtitle' => 'Сроки и виды охоты',
        'description' => '',
        'image' => 'okhota.jpg',
        'price' => '<i>3</i> 000',
        'href' => ' okhota.ru'),
    array(
        'name' => 'Рыбалка',
        'subtitle' => 'Виды рыбалки',
        'description' => '',
        'image' => 'rybalka.jpg',
        'price' => '<i>2</i> 000',
        'href' => 'rybalka.ru'),
);


?>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 right">
        <div class="price-wrapper">
            <!-- <button class="btn heading">
      <?php //print $service_item['btn']; ?>
    </button> -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php foreach ($data as $service_item){

        echo '<div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 left">
            <div class="heading">'.$service_item['name'].'</div>';
            if ($service_item['subtitle']) {
                echo '<div class="info">'.$service_item['subtitle'].'<i></i></div>';}
        echo '
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 text">
            <p>'.$service_item['description'].'</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 price-wrap">
            <div class="price heading">
                От <span>'.$service_item['price'].'</span> Рублей</div>
        </div>
        <a href="'.$service_item['href'].'">'.$service_item['name'].'</a>
    </div>
    </div>
';} ?>
```

Если использовать Ваш вариант, то, если я правильно Вас понял, то Вам необходимо имя ссылки передать в теге `<a>`, а саму ссылку в `href`.

```
<a href="<?php print $service_item['href']?>"><?php print $service_item['name']?></a>
```